# Find GCD of functions/polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\mathbb F$ be any field $a \neq b$ be two elements of $\mathbb F$

Find the GCD of $ f(x) = x + a $ and $g(x) = x + b$. Also find the polynomials $s(x)$ and $t(x)$ such that $s(x)f(x) + t(x)g(x)$ equals the GCD.

My work so far:

$d(x) = s(x)f(x)+t(x)g(x)$

$d(x) = s(x)[x+a] + t(x)[x+b]$

$d(x) = x[s(x) + t(x)] + s(x)*a +t(x)*a$

Thoughts on how I can find the polynomials? Is there an explicit solution for the GCD $d(x)$?

Comment: This question was [asked and answered](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/348642/how-to-compute-the-gcd-of-xa-and-xb-where-a-neq-b) a day or so ago.

Comment: Now that you know that, you could try to prove that the gcd of $X^n-1$ and $X^m-1$ is $X^k-1$ with $k$ the gcd of $m$ and $n$.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

if $a\neq b$, theyre coprime and $[(x+a)-(x+b)](a-b)^{-1}=1$

Comment: We know they are coprime because we can do a case such as a = 1 and b = 2?